# Manipulating variables indexed by a list

Tags: list-manipulation, indexed-variable

I have a variable g, indexed by a list:

```
g[{1,1}]=11;
g[{1,2}]=12;
g[{2,1}]=21;
g[{2,2}]=22;
```

I would like to move things around as follows:

```
g[{1,1}]=g[{2,1}];
g[{1,2}]=g[{2,2}];
```

but using

```
L1={{1,1},{1,2}};
L2={{2,1},{2,2}};
```

I tried `Map[g,L1]=Map[g,L2]` but that's not right. Is there a concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html):

```
MapThread[(g[#] = g[#2]) &, {L1, L2}]
(* {21, 22} *)

?g
(*
Global`g
g[{1,1}]=21
g[{1,2}]=22
g[{2,1}]=21
g[{2,2}]=22
*)
```

If you want to do everything in one go (e.g. if you want to swap elements), you can use the following approach:

```
(# = Map[g, L2]) &@Map[g, Unevaluated@# &@L1, {2}];

?g
(* same result *)
```

As you can see, this approach requires some careful evaluation control:

- In the end, we need `{g[…],g[…]}` on the left side of the assignment
- To do this, we want to pass `Unevaluated[{g[…],g[…]]` to the function `(# = …)&`.
- We have to map `g` over the list after we wrapped it in `Unevaluated`, otherwise it will just evaluate
- We need to force `L1` to be evaluated inside `Unevaluated`, hence the `Unevaluated@#&@L1`

Using `ReplaceAll`, it is a bit easier to build the final expression:

```
g /@ Hold @@ L1 /. Hold[lhs___] :> ({lhs} = Map[g, L2]);

?g
(* same result *)
```

Here, we build an expression of the form `Hold[g[…], g[…]]`, and then insert it into the assignment using `ReplaceAll`.